# How do I use libusb to make my monitor compatible with a usb-hdmi cable if it isn't already?

Tags: c++, libusb

the main problem that I'm facing is that i have no idea how to prepare the "frame buffer", and how to properly send it at some refresh rate (im guessing it's 60Hz)

The theory is, through knowledge of the hdmi protocol it should be possible to write software that takes in video memory from the windows PC and then transfers that through a USB medium into the PC monitor

edit #2: It seems that by simply creating a 2D array of 1920 pixels wide and  1080 pixels down it should be easy to use helper functions to send data to the monitor using a function that prepares the "packet" to be sent to the monitor

Unfortunately i don't have an hdmi with usb type A connector to test this using my monitor.

But essentially the idea is to write a start up-program that accomplishes this task using winAPI + libusb (ideally even before any users have already logged in).

The reason for this is because my micro usb port looks like is about to wear out doe to bent pins. I'd like to avoid downloading any software if possible.

edit: it doesn't have to be hdmi, vga or even rgb / composite is also considerable.

Comment: Are you saying that instead of buying a replacement micro-USB port and soldering it in, you want to write your own device driver?  I'm not sure which solution is more insane.

Comment: do you happen to know how to solder in a micro usb port?

Comment: @paddy i just found out how easy it is to solder this thing in, looks like that's the path im gonna take.

However, i would still like to educate myself about the internals of hdmi device drivers